# Can't install Thrift on Mac OS 10.9.2

Tags: macos, thrift, autotools

This problem is like [Installing thrift on CentOS 6.5 64 bit and Cassandra PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22548456/installing-thrift-on-centos-6-5-64-bit-and-cassandra-pdo)
, but he is on CentOS, I am runninc MacOS.

```
checking for gawk... (cached) awk
checking for ranlib... (cached) ranlib
./configure: line 17029: syntax error near unexpected token `QT,'
./configure: line 17029: `    PKG_CHECK_MODULES(QT, QtCore >= 4.3, QtNetwork >= 4.3, have_qt=yes, have_qt=no)'
```

My envrioment is

```
gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix

uname -a
Darwin rMacBook.local 13.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Wed Apr  2 23:52:02 PDT 2014; root:xnu-2422.92.1~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

add:

When i run `./bootstrap.sh`,the result is:

```
    lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:221: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:187: warning: variable 'processor_test_SOURCES' is defined but no program or
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:187: library has 'processor_test' as canonical name (possible typo)
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:178: warning: variable 'concurrency_test_SOURCES' is defined but no program or
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:178: library has 'concurrency_test' as canonical name (possible typo)
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:195: warning: variable 'processor_test_LDADD' is defined but no program or
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:195: library has 'processor_test' as canonical name (possible typo)
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:184: warning: variable 'concurrency_test_LDADD' is defined but no program or
lib/cpp/test/Makefile.am:184: library has 'concurrency_test' as canonical name (possible typo)
test/cpp/Makefile.am:96: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
tutorial/cpp/Makefile.am:65: warning: 'INCLUDES' is the old name for 'AM_CPPFLAGS' (or '*_CPPFLAGS')
```

Comment: When i run `./bootstrap.sh`,the result is:

Comment: Which Thrift version are you using? Have you tried updating gcc/autoconf as suggested in the other question?

Comment: yes,all plugins are the recent release.I use the source from http://thrift.apache.org/ and https://github.com/apache/thrift .This error is use github's source.The org's source is:src/generate/t_java_generator.cc:2830:14: error: incompatible operand types
      ('bool' and 'basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >')
                 first ? first = false : indent(f_service_) << "else ";
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [thrift-t_java_generator.o] Error 1

Comment: Could your first problem be related to [this one](http://myitcorner.com/blog/?p=207)? There's something wrong with your setup, and it is probably not related to Thrift per se. The second is [this one](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-2229) and it is a completely different problem which does not belong into this question.

Comment: Shouldn't this be migrated to apple.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 5):

Try following:

```
$ brew install pkg-config
```

I faced the same problem today and I didn't want to use `brew install thrift` as I have my boost installation in a custom location.

Installing `pkg-config` and then building a clean checkout of thrift worked.

Answer (score 3):

I just install thrift use brew.Because my brew version is too low.And I update my brew, it works.But when I update my brew,I meet a problem this--https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/28965#issuecomment-42163418
Thank all answers!

just command these：

```
brew update
brew install thrift
```

if update meet a problem like this：

```
undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

Just brew update again,it will work!

Answer (score 1):

How about installing [macports](http://macports.org) and simply doing:

```
$ sudo port install thrift
```

Answer (score 0):

For thrift 11, install brew first and then simply use this command:

```
brew install https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/4ba654c6d99b3b6804dd3843546a9dcbb700188b/Formula/thrift.rb
```